# How to bring all open apps back to desktop?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, shortcut-keys

In Ubuntu (22.04), `super + D` hide all opened apps and show the desktop. If `super + D` is pressed immediately after, all hidden apps are brought back to the desktop.

But if, right after hiding all apps, I open a new app, then `super + D` will hide the new opened app (and that's okay; this is the expected behavior for the `super + D` keystroke).

What I'm looking for is how to bring all apps back to the desktop, regardless how it was minimized.